# Why is the SHERPA dashboard visualization showing up blank?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, dashboard

I'm using the optimizer SHERPA to train a machine learning network. When the training begins, it lists a url that takes you to a built-in SHERPA dashboard to track the progress as it runs. The url is connected to a local host forwarding port specified within the code.

The training runs just fine within the docker, but I can't figure out why my visualization dashboard isn't working. Attached is a picture of what it's supposed to look like (from the SHERPA GitHub page) versus what I'm getting, which is blank. I let the training finish completely, which took multiple hours, but the dashboard still stayed blank the entire time. Any ideas?
[comparison image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlE6n.jpg)

Comment: Any update on this?